# How do I pass a path with spaces as a command line argument in a JSON file?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, anaconda3

I am trying to configure my settings.json file in VSCode to use an Anaconda prompt as the default terminal. My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.scrollback": 100000,
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "Anaconda Prompt": {
            "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
            "args": ["/K", "C:\\\"Program Files\"\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\activate.bat \"C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\""]
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Anaconda Prompt",
}
```

The problem I am having is with the arguments that are the paths to the activate.bat file and my Anaconda directory. Since Anaconda is located in the "Program Files" directory I am getting the error:

```
ArgumentError: activate does not accept more than one argument:
['"C:\\Program', 'Files\\Anaconda"']
```

I have tried using double quotes escaped around just the "Program Files" part, single quotes around the whole thing, and single quotes just around the 'Program Files' part.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should split "activate.bat" arg and the path to 2 separate args. And then quote whole lines (I think both single and double quotes should work). Like

```
["/K", "'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\activate.bat'", "'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda'"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, I didn't have any luck with your solution. I received the error `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Comment: Maybe changing places of single quotes and double quotes will fix it? I'm pretty sure that's solvable, I just don't have an opportunity to verify it on my end.